# Best Type of Pex Manifold

Tags: plumbing, pex

I am looking for recommendations on the best brand of PEX manifolds for a residence installation. Need one with shut off. I am concerned about the plastic based ones?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. But I have an answer despite that, since it's not a product recommendation...

Comment: If you are concerned about plastic, why aren't you concerned about the PEX itself?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at what was available, didn't like any of it, and simply ordered enough Tees (3/4 x 1/2 x 3/4 mostly, with a few 3/4 x 3/4 x 3/4) and valves to build my own from PEX (using a ring of 3/4" PEX as the "manifold."

Comment: A photo would be helpful.